# Convert .OGG files to .MP3 on GAE and PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a recording module in my website that is hosted on `GAE` that takes the user's microphone, records a `.OGG` file and then uploads it to `Google Cloud Storage`.

I'm trying to convert said file into a `.MP3` file when it's done recording without having to wait on the page for it to convert, but can't seem to find a way to do that with `PHP` on `GAE`. I've been looking at `FFMPEG` with `PHP`, and a `Task Queue`, but I'm not sure it will work on `GAE`.

What would be the best way to go about accomplishing this? Thanks for any input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video files conversion/transcoding Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997539/video-files-conversion-transcoding-google-app-engine)

Comment: try taskqueues and show us what failed